# How can I get projectile-grep et al to choose the project before searching?

Tags: projectile, grep, directory, helm-selection

Projectile-grep, projectile-ag et al always execute the search in the current file's project.

What I want to do is to select the project from a completion list and get projectile to search that project instead of having to open a file in the project directory and running the search from there.

Does emacs or projectile itself have some way of doing that? The only way I can think of for now is to get the completion dialog to open a buffer onto a file from that project and run the projectile-grep command after that. That seems clumsy some how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s-p p` (where `s-p` represents whatever prefix key you have chosen) will allow you to choose a different project. It then prompts you to open a file from that project; you can just open whatever file is first in the list for speed. Then do the search.

https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/configuration.html#switching-projects

Comment: I don't know how I've missed this for so long. Do the other project search systems to something similar?

Comment: Easy enough to miss one command in the midst of all the others. I only use Projectile, so I can’t compare it to alternatives.